# sort multidimensional array php by multiple fields with value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[3698] => Array
    (
        [brand] => Brand 1
        [rate] => 198
        [availability] => 0
        [stopsales] => 0
        [conditions] => 1
        [currencycode] => 1
    )

[1805] => Array
    (
        [brand] => Brand 2
        [rate] => 200,6
        [availability] => 0
        [stopsales] => 0
        [conditions] => 1
        [currencycode] => 1
    )

[1801] => Array
    (
        [brand] => Brand 3
        [rate] => 202,5
        [availability] => 0
        [stopsales] => 0
        [conditions] => 1
        [currencycode] => 1
    )

[1810] => Array
    (
        [brand] => Brand 1
        [rate] => 172
        [availability] => 0
        [stopsales] => 0
        [conditions] => 1
        [currencycode] => 1
    )
)
```

And I want it sorted first by Brand and then by Rate, like this:

```
Array
(
[3698] => Array
    (
        [brand] => Brand 1
        [rate] => 172
        [availability] => 0
        [stopsales] => 0
        [conditions] => 1
        [currencycode] => 1
    )

[1810] => Array
    (
        [brand] => Brand 1
        [rate] => 198
        [availability] => 0
        [stopsales] => 0
        [conditions] => 1
        [currencycode] => 1
    )

[1805] => Array
    (
        [brand] => Brand 2
        [rate] => 202,5
        [availability] => 0
        [stopsales] => 0
        [conditions] => 1
        [currencycode] => 1
    )

[1801] => Array
    (
        [brand] => Brand 1
        [rate] => 172
        [availability] => 0
        [stopsales] => 0
        [conditions] => 1
        [currencycode] => 1
    )
)
```

I already got it sorted by "brand" but it's doing it alphabetically, which it's not exactly what I need. The way the "brand" should be sorting is the following:

If I'm in Brand 2's website it should appear first, if I'm in Brand 3 then it should appear first and so on.

Currently I'm using this uasort with the following function:

```
function sortByBrandName($a, $b) {
//global $hotelBrand;
$brandName = strcmp($a['brand'], $b['brand']);
if($brandName === 0)
{
    return $brandName;
}
return $brandName;
}
```

And while it does sort the array by Brand, it doesn't do the trick depending on which site I'm currently on

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a needle (or a value) to compare (import) it inside `uasort` into your `uasort`, just use the `use` keyword along with your anonymous function with it. So that in your case, you could use *brand name* along with the sorting.

Simple Example:

```
$hotelBrand = 'Brand 3';
uasort($data, function ($a, $b) use ($hotelBrand) {
    $a1 = levenshtein($hotelBrand, $a['brand']);
    $b1 = levenshtein($hotelBrand, $b['brand']);
    if ($a1 === $b1) { // if same name sort by rate
        return $a['rate'] > $b['rate'] ? 1 : -1;
    } else if ($a1 != $b1) {
        return $a1 > $b1 ? 1 : -1;
    }   
    return 0;
});
```

[Sample Output](https://3v4l.org/jvO4g)

Comment: This did the job greatly! Thank you very much sir!!

Comment: @Agrus sure glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

```
array_multisort(array_column($data, 'brand'),  SORT_ASC,
                array_column($data, 'rate'), SORT_ASC,
                $data);
```

For Reference: http://php.net/array_multisort

Comment: Good one. I like it.. +1

Comment: While this does sort the array correctly, it doesn't solve that if I'm on Brand 3's site, it should appear first, not last :(

Comment: @Agrus Please check this key `1801` in both you input array and expected array.

Comment: @Agrus then use `SORT_DESC` flag for `brand` column.

Comment: Oh! This was a typo, it's supposed to be 1801 => array ( "brand" => "Brand 3")